# Getting deleted instance passed to merge : error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository

First Class is as : -
So here i am adding my created class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "performance_data_stage")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public  class PerfMetricEntity implements Serializable {

/** 
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2716603621710640771L;

@EmbeddedId
private PerfMetricEntityId perfMetricId;

@Column(name = "sample_count")
private double sampleCount;

@Column(name = "unit")
private String unit;

@Column(name = "avg_val")
private double averageValue;

@Column(name = "max_val")
private double maximumValue;

@Column(name = "min_val")
private double minimumValue;

@Column(name = "sum_val")
private double sumValue;

-------Getter & Setter Methods--------

}
```

Second Class :-

```
@Embeddable
public class PerfMetricEntityId implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7511513335470279948L;

@Column(name = "instance_id")
private String instanceId;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "metric_type")
private MetricType metricType;

@Column(name = "timestamp")
private Date timeStamp;

@Column(name = "period")
private int period;



/**
 * 
 */
public PerfMetricEntityId() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @param instanceId
 * @param metricType
 * @param timeStamp
 * @param period
 */
public PerfMetricEntityId(String instanceId, MetricType metricType, Date 
timeStamp, int period) {
    super();
    this.instanceId = instanceId;
    this.metricType = metricType;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.period = period;
}

}
```

And i have created repository as :-

---

---

```
public interface PerfMetricDetailsRepository extends 
JpaRepository<PerfMetricEntity, PerfMetricEntityId> {

@Query("SELECT p FROM PerfMetricEntity p WHERE p.perfMetricId.period = :period")
Page<PerfMetricEntity> findAllMetricTypeListByPeriod(@Param("period") int period,Pageable pageable);


@Query("delete from PerfMetricEntity")
Void DeleteAll();


}
```

So In my main function i am calling repository object lets "obj" .
I am calling method obj.DeleteAll() but giving the "deleted instance passed to merge error."
I seen many posts but most of them are on giving suggestion ,"Cascadetype" changing related things,but i havnt used any mapping i.e OneToOne,ManyToOne,..

Comment: I don't see/read any cause for merge in your code or description. Are you sure, you only call deleteAll?

Comment: Before Calling obj.DeleteAll() i am performing some actions as -Fetching  some data in batch and storing that data into new database table,then i want to delete old table from which data is fetched.so i am calling "obj.DeleteAll()

Comment: Could it be that one of the new entities has an active relation to one of the deleted entities?